# odd results inside of a switch statement

Tags: mysql, parsing, switch-statement

Thanks in advance to those who will have taken time to look at my issue.  I fetch results from a table that describe activities of a contractor.  There are a large number of True/False fields  and I seek only to display those that are true.  I create a field_name => field_type array and parse my display accordingly.  (apologies for the large code snippet.)

```
$result = $mysqli->query($visitsSQL);
if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ){ // Visit records don't exist
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Cannot find any unpaid visits";
    header("location: error.php");
}
else { // unpaid visits exist
    $fields= array();
    while ($finfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)){
    $fields [$finfo->name]= $finfo->type ; //this array holds field names -> field types    
    }  //finish fetching keys and types
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>Begin visit records<br>";
    echo "<div class='review_row'> </div>"; //this puts a thin line to separate visits

    while ($visit = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  //here's where each visit is compiled and sent to screen

        echo "<div class='review_row'>";  //this puts a thin line on the bottom to separate visits

     foreach ($fields as $k => $v) { 

        $field_name = $k;
        $field_type = $v;
        $field_data = $visit[$field_name];

        switch ($field_type) {

            case 1:   //The field is a True / False field
                if ($field_data ==1){  //show the field only if the value is set to True
                   echo "I am a YES/NO field called " . $field_name . " <br>";  //This line is a test 
                   echo "<span style='color: #009999;> - " . $field_name . "</span><br>";              
                }
                break;
            case 4:  //The field is a double numeric
                   if ($field_data != null) {       //show the field only if the value is set to True             
                echo "<span style='color: #b38f00';>" . $field_name . "</span>  " . $field_data . "<br>";  
                   }
                break;
            case 253: //A text field
                   if ($field_data != null) {                    
                echo "<span style='color: #b38f00';>" . $field_name . "</span>  " . $field_data . "<br>";  
                   }
                break;
            case 254: //a Datetime field
                   if ($field_data != null) {                    
                echo "<span style='color: #b38f00';>" . $field_name . "</span>  " . $field_data . "<br>";  
                   }
                break;
            default: { //field type is not represented above
              // do nothing so far  I take care of each field type above 
            }             
        }  //end of switch
    }  //end of foreach 
}  //end of while loop for the query results
echo "</div>";
```

}  // end of if / else that determine if there are records to display

The strange results occur in the "switch" statement where "case 1". My current test record has 7 YES/NO fields whose values are all set to 1.  They are

- Prepared evening meal
- Cleaned up evening meal dishes
- Shopped for groceries
- Washed and folded clothes
- Washed bedding
- Vacuumed carpets
- Swept kitchen floor

I should get two "echo"s for each "field_type = 1": (1) my test echo and (2) what I eventually want to display, but for some reason they display alternately - see image below.  I've fought with this for two days, trying if/then parsing as well, but I come up with this "every-second-one" type of result.

[`screenshot of output from query`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSLQR.png)

Thanks for any thoughts or direction.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem & corrected it.  It had to do with the "span..." tags.  I replaced the inline "style=..." with a class. I set the the color within the class then removed settings with an "class: after" section.